# .net core aws eb deploy in Visual Studio 2015 cannot resolve dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015, dnx, project.json, .net-core

I have a .net core project in Visual Studio 2015 and I am trying to deploy to an AWS EB environment and I am getting about 400 errors about not being able to resolve dependencies, such as: `project.json(19,66): error NU1001: The dependency EntityFramework.Core >= 7.0.0-rc1-final could not be resolved.`

I have tried to run the `dotnet build` command from my directory as well and I get the same error, so the error is within my project, and not with AWS.

I believe it is something that has to do with my project.json or some some configuration in my project, but I do not know what.

This is my `project.json` file, if it helps:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "webroot":  "wwwroot",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "MimeKit": "1.3.0-beta7",
    "MailKit": "1.3.0-beta7",
    "Google.Apis.Auth": "1.11.1"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "userSecretsId": "----"
}
```

The project does run and can be deployed to a local directory and then uploaded via ftp to a iis webserver and it works correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by running the `dotnet restore` command from my package manager console